# InterstitialAd in specified activity

Tags: java, android, webview

I work on this activity
 Please tell me
 How I can show interstitial Ad before redirecting user to google play store?

Is it possible?

```
 public class MyClinet extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("myhostsite")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().equals("market")) {
            try {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                Activity host = (Activity) view.getContext();
                host.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // Google Play app is not installed, you may want to open the app store link
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                view.loadUrl("http://play.google.com/store/apps/" + uri.getHost() + "?" + uri.getQuery());
                return false;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this official google tutorial and you will achieve what you want https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

But the core is to add a listener to your interstitial add and redirect the user when the ad is closed. Like this:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Your redirect code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok Thank you @André Sousa I hope it will works as I want.

Comment: Was you add loaded?

Comment: If that is the case and the ad is no shown, there should be an error in yours logs related with the ads API.

Comment: Can I talk with you in private like facebook or twitter?